# Regular expression to match up to the first space of a line not preceeded by a comma

Tags: regex, dictionary, text, multiple-entries, pcre2

I'm editing a large dictionary file and the term and definition pairs do not have a consistent format. Some words are "simple", some words include the base term plus some suffix to alter things like its gender, basically stacking two terms into one entry:

```
abacora (definition)
abacorar  (definition)
abad, desa (definition)
```

This last term means "abad" and "abadesa" (feminine variant).

I've been trying to write the regular expression to capture this "peculiarity" but I can't seem to make it work. This matches the first part of the term fine, but fails to capture the second part:

```
^[^\s(?<!,)]+
```

It should return:

```
"abacora"
"abacorar"
"abad, desa"
```

Comment: why are there double-quote characters in the output?

Comment: `^(?:,\s|\S)+` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is just a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match anything other than whitespace or one of `(`, `?`, `<`, `!`, `,` or `)`. What you need to do is match up to a space which is not preceded by a comma, which could do with this regex:

```
^(?:, |[^ ])+
```

This matches:

- `(?:, |[^ ])+` : one or more of **either**:

  - `,`  : a comma followed by a space; **or**
  - `[^ ]` : a character which is not a space

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CRTazI/1)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do what I'm looking for. I just changed ' ' to '\s' in order to make it work in case words are separated by a tabulator or something. "^(?:,\s|[^\s])+"

Comment: @M1KEMEX fair enough, I just simplified based on your sample data, but if you might have tabs as well as spaces, then what you propose is the way to go.

Comment: @M1KEMEX note that if your regex engine supports it, you might want to use `\h` (horizontal whitespace) rather than `\s`, as that could potentially match a newline which might not be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following pattern, which should capture all leading words possibly including a CSV list:

```
^\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*
```

This pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the line
- `\w+` match a word
- `(?:,\s*\w+)*` optionally followed by a CSV list of other words

### Demo

**Edit:**

More generally, we can match on `[^,\s]+` for a non whitespace, non comma, character, and use this pattern:

```
^[^,\s]+(?:,\s*[^,\s]+)*
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. This works kind of fine, but it's limited to English. That's why I wanted to use the inverted form: to match anything that is not white space, in order to capture letters from other languages or symbols.

Comment: @M1KEMEX Your question did not make this clear.  I have edited my pattern to match more generally for any type of character.

Comment: Yes, I did not mention it explicitly. Your help is greatly appreciated.